# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android

In my App am received following Error message

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

What is the solution for this?

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

delete all "build" sub directories and re-build the whole project.

Comment: After re-building I get this error
Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 11

Comment: I changed the line "minSdkVersion 8" to "minSdkVersion 11". But this error appears: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Comment: This error in general means that you've tried to link in the same class to your project more than once, which isn't allowed.Can you please post the logcat.

Comment: maybe some of your jar files does not compile. You should go into your build.gradle file in your project, and look in your dependencies.

If you're just importing some jar files, you could try to remove them and add them one at a time. This will help you determine which one of them causes the error.

Comment: I removed all jar files one by one but the error persists.